# jQuery Knob displays NaN when value is 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-knob

It's really weird.

```
$(function(){
    $('.dial').knob({
       return value + '%';
    });
});
```

That was my original code to get the percent sign to show up, which works great. For some reason, when the value is 0, on page load it displays as `NaN`. The weird thing is that only once you highlight the text and then click off does it show the actual value of 0 (replacing the `NaN` value). Any idea what is causing this to happen? I tried to handle it in the format hook:

```
$(function(){
    $('.dial').knob({
       'format': function( value ){
           if(value == undefined || value == NaN {
             value = 0; 
             return value + '%';
           }
           else{
             return value + '%';
           }
        } 
    });
});
```

It still doesn't work. I console logged the value I'm passing in, and sure enough it is 0. I'm thinking it may be an 'x loads before y' and therefore it sees the value as undefined, since I am passing in the value attribute by an angularJS data binding. But I'm trying to handle it to no avail. Any thought's on this?

Comment: Are you sure your conditional check is working ok? I always use `if(typeof(value) == 'undefined'...` .  Might be worth a try.

Comment: I'll try that and let you know.

Comment: Also, debugging this in Firebug or similar would show you exactly what's happening.

Comment: Still didn't work. I am starting to think more and more that it is an issue with the jQuery knob loading before my angular data bindings. And I don't think the 'format' hook is able to do any handling other than appending something to the value, because the conditional checks aren't doing anything.

Comment: `value == NaN` will not work because, surprisingly, in javascript `NaN` does not equal `NaN`. try `isNaN()` instead. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN

Comment: I'm now trying to use ng-if or ng-switch on the jquery knob input element. This hides the input, but the knob generates a canvas when it gets hit and now 2 canvases are showing up, which is leading me to believe it's a timing issue. The second canvas is showing up with no <input/>.

Comment: @yarons you called it. Write it as an answer and I'll mark it as correct. Thanks for everyones input, I really appreciate it!

Comment: @Matt MacLeod - cool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`value == NaN` will not work because, surprisingly, in javascript `NaN` does not equal `NaN`. try [isNaN()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) instead.